# Eloquent relationship confusion

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a model, `Foo`, which has three fields, `id`, `title`, and `image_id`. `image_id` references the `id` on an `images` table.

I have the relationship set up like this:

**Foo.php:**

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Image');
}
```

**Image.php:**

```
public function foos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Foo');
}
```

I thought I would be able to get the image of a Foo with this:

```
$foo = Foo::find(1);
$image = $foo->image;
```

But this is giving me the error:

> Unknown column 'images.foo_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `images` where `images`.`foo_id` = 1 and `images`.`foo_id` is not null limit 1)"

Comment: Please try my answer too below )))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your relationships are wrong.    The relationship is a one-to-many.  You have a one-to-one defined in Foo and a many-to-many defined in Image.

1. Foo belongs to one image, so that would be a belongsTo relationship.
2. Images could have many foos, so that would be a hasMany relationship.

Comment: Everything ok, but if you add unique to the image_id, it converts into a hasOne. He doesn't said that, but is not necessarily a hasMany

Comment: You're right but I figured it was safe to assume one to many from the use of belongsToMany on Image.

Comment: Yeah, and i assumed it was a hasOne since he says "I thought I would be able to get the image of a Foo with this" ... lol ! GluePear if you want to get a direct object use hasOne, but as it says will only return one... if you want multiple images to iterate on, use what Devon said

Comment: Well, the hasOne would be on the Image, not Foo, because the image_id resides in the foos table.  So it would still be belongsTo and able to get a single image of Foo using the above relationships.  (One to one and one to many doesn't affect the Foo::image relationship)

Comment: oh you are right, is the image_id that can be in many foos, my bad. so with would be backwards... if you want a direct object of FOO use hasOne... etc...

Answer (score 2):

Your relationship are not set properly.

When you store the foreign key in the table, this is the child one. In this case `Foo` has an `Image` but an `Image` can be used in one or many `Foo`s so:

```php
Image 1 ---- m Foo

// or if the image is unique for every Foo object
Image 1 ---- 1 Foo
```

This means:

**Foo.php**

```php
public function image()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Image');
}
```

**Image.php**

```php
public function foos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Foo');

    // or if its unique:
    // return $this->hasOne('App\Foo');
}
```

Comment: As i pointed in the other answer: Everything ok, but if you add unique to the image_id, it converts into a hasOne. He doesn't said that, but is not necessarily a hasMany

Comment: Yeah, nice observation.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... The `hasOne` relationship does that... looks for a `foo_id` on your `image` table.

You should use `belongsTo` on `Foo` and `hasOne` or `hasMany` on image...

Or redeclare your migration tables... the other way

A model, `Foo`, two fields, `id`, `title`. And `foo_id` on `image` table references the `id` on `foo` table.

Answer (score 0):

Change your models to this...
Image model should have these columns 'foo_id' ,'image_path'.

### And remove 'image_id'  column  from your Foo model.

Inside of create function in  Foocontroller...

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->title = $request->title;
$foo->save();

$pathToImage = Storage::put('images/',$request-        >file('image'));
$image = new Image();
$image->image_path = $pathToImage;
$image->foo_id  = $foo->id;
$image->save();
```

---

Inside of Foo model...

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Image');
}
```

Inside of Image model...

```
public function foo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Foo');
}
```

fetching your foo item from database

```
$foos = Foo::all();
foreach ($foos as $foo){
       echo  $foo->title;
       echo  $foo->image->image_path;
}
```